# HTML Anchors Navigation Not Working With CSS Sticky Stack

Tags: html, css, anchor

I'm building a website where there is a navbar on the top and then as I navigate down on the page there are section titles being stacked as sticky below the navbar. What I've noticed is that when the "top" CSS tag is used in an element, the HTML anchors get broken.

I've coded the example in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lbfk1a5z/). When the page is loaded, you can navigate through the top navbar to ID1, ID2, ID3 and ID4. The problem is that for instance when you get to ID2, you can't get back to ID1, or get from ID3 to ID1 or ID2. Basically you can't use the anchors of any stacked sticky element that uses the "top" CSS tag which located higher on the page.

This doesn't  makes sense to me. Any ideas of why this is and any ideas on how to workaround?

Thanks in advance to all the responses.

Code example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <style>
    .topnav {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 99;
      border: #f1f1f1;
}
    .stickytitle{
      list-style-type: none;
      float: left;
      margin: 0;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: seagreen;
      position: sticky;
      top: 20px;
      border-radius: 0px;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #eee;
      z-index: 98;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<div class="topnav">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#id1">ID1</a>
  <a href="#id2">ID2</a>
  <a href="#id3">ID3</a>
  <a href="#id4">ID4</a>
</div> 

<h1 class="stickytitle" id="id1">ID1</h1>
<p>TO TEST INSERT LONG TEXT HERE OR CHECK THE JSFIDDLE REFERRED ABOVE</p>
<h1 class="stickytitle" id="id2">ID2</h1>
<p>TO TEST INSERT LONG TEXT HERE OR CHECK THE JSFIDDLE REFERRED ABOVE</p>
<h1 class="stickytitle" id="id3">ID3</h1>
<p>TO TEST INSERT LONG TEXT HERE OR CHECK THE JSFIDDLE REFERRED ABOVE</p>
<h1 class="stickytitle" id="id4">ID4</h1>
<p>TO TEST INSERT LONG TEXT HERE OR CHECK THE JSFIDDLE REFERRED ABOVE</p>

</html>
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense to me. The h1 headlines before the current one, are not in the place any more that they used to be in, in normal flow - _because_ you made them sticky. So clicking those anchor links jumps to the corresponding headline - but it is not where you _want_ it to be at this point. Wrap your headlines and the following text content into a container element, and put the ID that you are trying to jump to, on that container element, instead of the sticky headline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CBroe pointed out, you need to create sections/wrappers that do not become sticky.

```css
section {
  min-height: 50vh;
}
.topnav {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
  border: #f1f1f1;
}
.stickytitle{
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: seagreen;
  position: sticky;
  top: 20px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #eee;
  z-index: 98;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#id1">ID1</a>
  <a href="#id2">ID2</a>
  <a href="#id3">ID3</a>
  <a href="#id4">ID4</a>
</div> 

<section id="id1">
  <h1 class="stickytitle">ID1</h1>
  <p>TO TEST INSERT LONG TEXT HERE OR CHECK THE JSFIDDLE REFERRED ABOVE</p>
</section>
<section id="id2">
  <h1 class="stickytitle">ID2</h1>
  <p>TO TEST INSERT LONG TEXT HERE OR CHECK THE JSFIDDLE REFERRED ABOVE</p>
</section>
<section id="id3">
  <h1 class="stickytitle">ID3</h1>
  <p>TO TEST INSERT LONG TEXT HERE OR CHECK THE JSFIDDLE REFERRED ABOVE</p>
</section>
<section id="id4">
  <h1 class="stickytitle">ID4</h1>
  <p>TO TEST INSERT LONG TEXT HERE OR CHECK THE JSFIDDLE REFERRED ABOVE</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Many thanks @prettyInPink 

This is the correct way to do it and it makes perfect sense